# when Perform to "this.getReadableDatabase",skip the following code and throws Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 public List<MedicalCase> getPersonalCase(int personid) {

    Cursor c = null;
    MedicalCase mMedicalCase = new MedicalCase();
    List<MedicalCase> myList = new ArrayList<MedicalCase>();

    try {

        synchronized (DBLOCK) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String str_personid = String.valueOf(personid);
            c = db.query(true, TABLE_Case, new String[]{MedicalCase_CaseId, MedicalCase_CaseCoverImageFileName,
                            MedicalCase_CaseColor, MedicalCase_CaseName,
                            MedicalCase_StartDate, MedicalCase_EndDate},
                    Person_PersonId + " = ?", new String[]{str_personid}, null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    mMedicalCase.setCaseId(c.getColumnIndex(MedicalCase_CaseId));
                    mMedicalCase.setCaseCoverImageFileName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MedicalCase_CaseCoverImageFileName)));
                    mMedicalCase.setCaseColor(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MedicalCase_CaseColor)));
                    mMedicalCase.setCaseName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MedicalCase_CaseName)));
                    mMedicalCase.setStartDate(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MedicalCase_StartDate)));
                    mMedicalCase.setEndDate(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MedicalCase_EndDate)));
                    myList.add(mMedicalCase);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return myList;
}
```

This is my code ,when Perform to `this.getReadableDatabase`,skip the following code and throws Exception,but not  go to `String str_personid = String.valueOf(personid);`

I think that  it is maybe the `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase()` is NullPointer,but i dont sure if  it is wrong.

Comment: Paste the stacktrace (logcat).

Comment: E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices

Comment: E/TimelyPrefService﹕ Primary account is null

Comment: E/ConfigContainer﹕ init appKey with:12679450

Comment: Please edit your question is hard to say it from comments without formatting.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
            at com.luckyxmobile.familyhealthtracker.provider.FamilyHealthSQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(FamilyHealthSQLiteOpenHelper.java:270)
            at com.luckyxmobile.familyhealthtracker.provider.FamilyHealthSQLiteOpenHelper.getPersonalCase(FamilyHealthSQLiteOpenHelper.java:941)

Comment: The  problem is NullPointer

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Comment: Are you checked the context is not null?

Comment: Thank u very much!  the context is null